# how to recover from message store exhaustion?

Tags: activemq-classic, recovery, cluster-computing

when a activemq broker gets flooded with messages or the consumer fails it will stop accepting messages once certain (configurable) limits are reached. In Broker Networks this effect can take down the whole cluster.

I'm currently using the default configuration for memory limits and experience the following behavior:

1. consumer fails or becomes very slow (known problem)
2. broker A (the one the consumer connects to) gets filled and stops accepting messages
3. all other brokers get filled up and stop to accept messages
4. the cluster is basicly down

if the consumer comes back online now it will try to reconnect to one of the cluster nodes but the nodes will not accept the connection becaus this would create advisory messages that can't be handled because the broker is already full.

How do i have to configure the memory limits so that my productive destinations are limited and blocked but the broker will still be able to accept advisories so my consumer can revover?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [producerFlowControl](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html) to slow producers to not overwhelm your broker.  That being said, this is enabled by default, so you are likely using it already...

I would try something like this (assuming an 8GB box or so)...

- use the [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) transport everywhere (broker/client connections)
- increase JVM heap to 4 GB
- increase systemUsage limits substantially (memoryUsage 3gb, storeUsage/tempUsage = 10 gb)
- enable producer flow control on both topics and queues

  - set the memory limit to 2GB divided by the total # of topics+queues
  - in other words, this should in total be substantially less the the memoryUsage limit
  - exclude the Advisory topics from the producer flow control (they might be already)

This **should** limit the producers and leave resources for your system to function/recover/accept consumer connections...